# Combining 2 data sets in excel where a certain value can corresponds to multiple pairs

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem where I want to combine 2 data sets. The difficult part is that certain value may have more than one pair of data and if it happens I need to combine both entry.
E.g:

```
Data 1                   Data 2
|Name |Pets|             |Name  |Number|
|Al   |Cat |             |Al    |1     | 
|Al   |Dog |             |Ben   |2     |
|Ben  |Cat |             |Chris |3     |
```

Result I want is :

```
|Name |Pets    |Number|
|Al   |CatDog  |1     |
|Ben  |Cat     |2     |
|Chris|        |3     |
```

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to do without VBA, you need to write a macro to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Found part of the answer in another post. So I will close this post. It is a bit tedious without macro but here is how I do it:

1. Combined all the data in pet with the same Name, then store it in third column
2. Remove all the entry which third column is not the full combination
3. use =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(),"") method to match each name with the correct number.

Here is the link for the post I mentioned before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754501/combining-duplicate-entries-with-unique-data-in-excel/15756028#15756028